# ionic geolocation plugin error: "No provider for Geolocation"

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to use geolocation in my ionic2 hello world project, and I add the ionic plugin "Geolocation" following the instruction on the [official site](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/geolocation/).

I've run these two commands:

```
$ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/geolocation
```

And this is my home.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Geolocation} from '@ionic-native/geolocation'
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  map:any=null;
  geoInfo:any={
      resp:'',
      data:''
  };

  constructor(
      public navCtrl: NavController,
      private geolocation: Geolocation
  ) {

  }
  
  test(){
      this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
          this.geoInfo.resp=JSON.stringify(resp);
          // resp.coords.latitude
          // resp.coords.longitude
      }).catch((error) => {
          console.log('Error getting location', error);
          this.geoInfo.resp='Error getting location';
      });

      let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
      watch.subscribe((data) => {
          this.geoInfo.data=JSON.stringify(data);
          // data can be a set of coordinates, or an error (if an error occurred).
          // data.coords.latitude
          // data.coords.longitude
      });

  }

}
```

However, I got the following error in my chrome's console:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./TabsPage class TabsPage - inline template:0:0 caused by: No provider for Geolocation!
error_handler.js:56ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Geolocation!
```

[image: screenshot]

At first I thought it was because I was debugging in browser, but then I got then same error in my Android phone.

So what does `No provider for Geolocation` mean and how should I use geolocation in my ionic2 project?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You need to add the provider to the NgModule, i.e module.ts under providers,

```
providers: [
  Geolocation
]
```

Comment: After adding Geolocation to `app.module.ts`, I got a new error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Geolocationa is not defined`.

Comment: check for the spelling Geolocationa

Answer (score 13):

You need to import the Geolocation class and add it to your list of providers in the app.module.ts file

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

providers: [
     Geolocation
]
```

Comment: In Ionic 4 when I add Geolocation to providers I get this error: `Invalid provider for the NgModule 'AppModule' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [AuthGuardService, StatusBar, SplashScreen, ?[object Object]?, ...]`, the last one is the Geolocation

Comment: @devnosaur, you have to use import like: `import {Geolocation} from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';`

Comment: @EgorMedvedev Thank you! The `/ngx` was the key for me in Ionic 4! You should make that into an answer so it's easier to find.

Answer (score 12):

For **Ionic 4** you add to `app.module.ts` top:

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
```

And on the bottom, inside of the `Providers` array, add `Geolocation`:

```
providers: [
    Geolocation,
    ...
]
```

Comment: I confirm that this works perfectly as of Feb 2020. Thanks a ton for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

that worked for me, I had it imported everywhere but had forgotten to add it to the providers on app.module.ts
    app.module.ts

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

providers: [
StatusBar,
SplashScreen,
{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
AuthService,
EmailValidator,
DataService,
Geolocation
]
```

then on the page I was displaying the lat and long to in this instance as a test home;

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
lat: number;
longt: number;

this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
  this.lat = (resp.coords.latitude);
  this.longt =(resp.coords.longitude);
 }).catch((error) => {
   console.log('Error getting location', error);
 });
```

then on home.html {{lat}} {{longt}}

I know it was only simple but I was just getting the data out before moving onto to placing it into map.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I face it that I had my native core plugins was not in the same versions into my package.json.

You can check for this solution and this other article at the followings:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cant-resolve-peer-dependencies-after-update/107224/2
https://blog.ionicframework.com/help-test-ionic-native-5/

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native

Comment: what is the specific instructions from these links which would help resolve the question?

Answer (score 0):

In **2022**, the following works for me:

**I had to do the following changes in order for Geolocation to work:**

> ionic integrations disable capacitor

> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation

> npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/geolocation

> npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/core

What the above commands do, in the specified order, is to disable the capacitor integration as cordova plugin will not be installed alongside of the capacitor version. Then install the geolocations plugins and also install the core or else the angular compiler will throw an error.

In **app.module.ts**, add the following:

```
import { Geolocation } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/geolocation/ngx';

providers: [Geolocation],
```

Once all the above has been configured, within the page where you need the geolocation to trigger, you may add the following code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Geolocation } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/geolocation/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.page.scss'],
})
export class DashboardPage implements OnInit {

  latitude: any;
  longitude: any;

  constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
      this.latitude = resp.coords.latitude;
      this.longitude = resp.coords.longitude;
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error getting location', error);
    });
  }

}
```

You will now be able to show the coordinates in the HTML page like so:

```
{{latitude}} <---> {{longitude}}
```